# If you "visit" a doctor or a hairdresser, does it mean that you come to their houses?

Tags: word-meaning

For example, if I say,

> I visited a barber yesterday.

how would I be understood by a native speaker? That I had my hair cut or that I came to his or her house while he or she wasn't at work? I know that it's not how you usually say it but still (you say, 'go to the barber's/hairdresser's', right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Visit X* does tend to imply "go over to X's place", but the place doesn't have to be a home, it can be an office, place of business, or cubicle.

So the listener of your example will assume you went to a barbershop, unless it was known beforehand that the barber cuts hair at home.

Comment: So it's a perfectly okay way to talk about getting your hair cut? It's not flawed in any way, is it?

Comment: It sounds natural to me. I think it's a slightly less casual choice of words than, say, "went to," but nobody will notice it as being strange.